# Bind ArrayList with ListView - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I am trying to bind `ListView` with `ArrayList` on a button click `(btnGetPost)` . I am very very very new to Android programming. Right now i am able to retrieve the Facebook Group Posts as a JSON Response. Then i am looping through this JSON object and adding all the messages to an `ArrayList`.

Now my question is, how do i display all the messages in a `ListView` on a `button click`. I mean how do i bind this `ArrayList` to a `ListView` ? Kindly point me in the right direction.

```
package org.example.fbapp;



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class FBAppActivity extends Activity {

    // Your Facebook APP ID
    private static String APP_ID = "********************";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    // data JSONArray
    JSONArray data = null;

    // Instance of Facebook Class
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> messages = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Buttons

    Button btnGetPost;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fbapp);


        btnGetPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_group_posts);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);


        /**
         * Get Posts from Group
         * */
        btnGetPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getGPosts();
            }
        });


    }



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



    /**
     * Get Group Posts by making request to Facebook Graph API
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getGPosts() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("203153109726651/feed", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("GET POSTS", response);
                String json = response;

                try {

                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray finalObj = obj.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < finalObj.length(); i++) {

                        final String message = finalObj.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("message");

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        messages.add(map);


                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Name: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }

                        });
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you have data in your arraylist,

then you can put it into adapter which will load data to views in listview

ListView and Adapter BasicsHow it works:

1. ListView asks adapter “give me a view” (getView) for each item of the list
2. A new View is returned and displayed

So you can try to override **BaseAdapter**

An example of overriding BaseAdapter:
You can just Pay Attention to `getView` method. That's pretty much the essence of adapter.

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Then you can simply do the following to your `ListView view;`

```
view.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

More detailed explanation in this blog
http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

(which isn't mine. i copied the sample code and some of the explanation from this page)

Answer (score 0):

You bind your data to the ListView through its Adapter. In this case it would be useful to write your own Adapter derived from [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)
You can keep a reference of your data as a member of the custom Adapter.

Comment: Please show me some sample code. As i mentioned in the question that i am new to Android Programming, I am unable to follow you.